# grep a command output, but how to look for specific block?

Tags: grep

I'm looking for some specific block with grep

**for example I have this output from android device:**

```
Stream volumes (device: index)
- STREAM_VOICE_CALL:
   Muted: false
   Min: 1
   Max: 5
   Current: 40000000 (default): 4
   Devices: earpiece
- STREAM_SYSTEM:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 7
   Current: 40000000 (default): 5
   Devices: speaker
- STREAM_RING:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 7
   Current: 40000000 (default): 5
   Devices: speaker
**- STREAM_MUSIC:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 2 (speaker): 12, 4000000 (usb_headset): 3, 40000000 (default): 8
   Devices: speaker**
- STREAM_ALARM:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 7
   Current: 40000000 (default): 6
   Devices: speaker
- STREAM_NOTIFICATION:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 7
   Current: 40000000 (default): 5
   Devices: speaker
- STREAM_BLUETOOTH_SCO:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 40000000 (default): 7
   Devices: earpiece
- STREAM_SYSTEM_ENFORCED:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 7
   Current: 40000000 (default): 5
   Devices: speaker
- STREAM_DTMF:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 40000000 (default): 11
   Devices: speaker
- STREAM_TTS:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 2 (speaker): 12, 4000000 (usb_headset): 3, 40000000 (default): 8
   Devices: speaker
- STREAM_ACCESSIBILITY:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 2 (speaker): 12, 4000000 (usb_headset): 3, 40000000 (default): 8
   Devices: speaker
```

I need to get the block within ** ** with grep, which code grep command do I need to find that specific block of output?
I've tried with

> adb shell dumpsys audio | grep {STREAM_MUSIC:,STREAM_ALARM} and
>   returns nothing  adb shell dumpsys audio | grep -w  STREAM_MUSIC
>   returns only the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use `awk`, you can do this:

```
awk '/- STREAM/ {f=0} /- STREAM_MUSIC:/ {f=1} f'
- STREAM_MUSIC:
   Muted: false
   Min: 0
   Max: 15
   Current: 2 (speaker): 12, 4000000 (usb_headset): 3, 40000000 (default): 8
   Devices: speaker
```

Comment: thank you, is very useful but is this not possible with grep?

Comment: @EdgarL Not all tool can do everything.  `grep` is good on finding things, `awk` is good on working with multiple lines.

Comment: I find out with adb shell dumpsys audio | grep -A 5 STREAM_MUSIC i got the same result